# Java JDBC throwing an error for an SQL query asking to return details from only particular rows

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

I have a database called 'airplane' inside which there is a table named booking.
The booking table has the columns phone(int type) ,name(text type),address(text type),city(text type) destination(text type),date(text type). I want to fetch only the rows whose phone column has value or data equal to phone number entered by the user . I wrote the following code for it . For context , I am using java using  JDBC

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airplane";
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "";

Connection conn = null;



try
  {
    System.out.println("enter cell no");
    int cell=sc.nextInt();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

   // My SQL SELECT query.

    String query = "SELECT * FROM `booking` where phone=cell";

   // creating the java statement
   Statement st = conn.createStatement();

   /** executing the query, and getting a java resultset of all rows whose phone
    column has the value equal to one entered by user and stored by me in 
  int variable cell**/

   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

         //iterate through the java resultset
         while (rs.next())
           {
            int Phone = rs.getInt("phone");
            String Name = rs.getString("name");
            String Address = rs.getString("address");
            String City = rs.getString("city");
            String Destination = rs.getString("destination");
            String Date = rs.getString("date");

// print the results
           System.out.format("%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", Phone, Name, Address, City, Destination, Date);
                       }

                        st.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
```

I am getting the error:

```
Got an exception! 
Unknown column 'cell' in 'where clause'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `booking` where phone=" + cell;
```

A better way to handle this is to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

This case, the query would look like:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `booking` where phone=?"
```

and

```
statement.setInt(1, cell);
```

Answer (score -1):

you will see it's gonna run

String query = "SELECT * FROM `booking` where phone="+"\"%s\"";

query=String.format(query,cell);

Comment: Better to get into the habit to use PreparedStatement, though.